# Custom Root Container Doesn't Load Correctly

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

In my kendo mobile application, if I have a custom root container like so:

```
<div id="appcontainer">
    <div data-layout="StandardLayout" data-role="view" data-title="My Group List" id="MainView">
        This is the first contents.
    </div>

    <div data-layout="StandardLayout" data-role="view" data-title="View Group" id="SelectedView">
        This is the second contents.
    </div>

    <div data-role="layout" id="StandardLayout">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <a data-role="backbutton" data-align="left" href="nav-button">Back</a>              
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <footer data-role="footer"> 
        </footer>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window["appframework"] = new kendo.mobile.Application($("#appcontainer").get(0));
</script>
```

The Kendo mobile framework does not initialize the views correctly, and I get the error:

> Error: Your kendo mobile application element does not contain any
>   direct child elements with data-role="view" attribute set. Make sure
>   that you instantiate the mobile application using the correct
>   container.

But if I remove the appcontainer element, and use `document.body` as the root element, everything works fine.  Any idea why a custom root container doesn't work?

Comment: Your code does work in this jsBin (though I had to change the Layout id to data-id):
http://jsbin.com/ilazuw/2/

Maybe you've missed to copy something important over?

Comment: Huh, maybe that's all that it is.  Thanks!